# Rails button_to doesn't hide parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just can't get things right inside `button_to`. What is wrong with the following code? I get the error message `missing required keys: [:callsign]`.
Attempt 1:

```
<%= button_to messages_user_path,
              callsign: @character.callsign,
              params: {
                recipient_callsign: notice.character.callsign
              },
              class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs post_button',
              id: 'message_envelope' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

This also fails with the same error message:
Attempt 2:

```
<%= button_to messages_user_path(
                params: {
                  callsign: @character.callsign,
                  recipient_callsign: notice.character.callsign
                }
              ),
              class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs post_button',
              id: 'message_envelope' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

This version shows the page, but it doesn't hide the `recipient_callsign`, which can be seen in the url. This defeats the object of using `button_to` in the first place because I don't want `recipient_callsign` in the url. Why doesn't it hide `recipient_callsign`?
Attempt 3:

```
<%= button_to messages_user_path(
                callsign: @character.callsign,
                params: {
                  recipient_callsign: notice.character.callsign
                }
              ),
              class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs post_button',
              id: 'message_envelope' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= button_to 'Button text', messages_user_path(callsign: @character.callsign),
   class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs post_button',
   id: 'message_envelope',
   params: {
     recipient_callsign: notice.character.callsign
   }
  do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

First lets separate the path helper method:

```
messages_user_path(callsign: @character.callsign)
```

Path and url helpers take a hash. Any keys provided except the named keys will be added to the query string.

Take this example:

```
micropost_path(id: 6)    
=> "/microposts/6"
micropost_path(id: 6, foo: 'bar')
=> "/microposts/6?foo=bar"
```

The signature for button_to is basically:

```
<%= button_to 'text', action, options = {} %>
```

You add inputs to the form with the `params` option.

```
{
  class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs post_button',
  id: 'message_envelope',
  params: {
     recipient_callsign: notice.character.callsign
   }
}
```

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Although it only worked once I removed 'Button text' ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986559/rails-undefined-method-stringify-keys )

Comment: Oh, yeah, you where using a block :)