# Looping over an element in Rails 4 that encloses other elements with loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running issues using a `link_to` through a loop when there is another element encompassing the looped attributes.

Here's what I mean. I am showing posts for a blog in an image - this image will contain multiple elements of content, all of which are being pulled from my table in Rails.

With a stub as the link, this works fine, and it contains all of the image/post content within an `<a>` link:

```
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img alt="rss feed" src="http://www.example/image.png" />
      <h1>Business Business Business </h1>
      <p>Ipsum Incorporated is going to do something</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That said, I want it to attach the associated link from my `Stub` column in my `Post` table, so I will adjust the code like so:

```
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <%= link_to post.slug, about_path(post.slug), class: "hexIn" %>
      <img alt="rss feed" src="http://www.example/image.png" />
      <h1>Business Business Business </h1>
      <p>Ipsum Incorporated is going to do something</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now I thought this looked great. I am still changing the link to be the `hexIn` class. However, the image posts end up being distorted and clearly wrong.

After looking at the source code, I noticed that Rails is successfully changing `href` to the link from the table (good!) but attaching a closing ` after the link. Since in the original code, this link remains open until line 7, I believe that's causing the issue.

```
<a class="hexIn" href="/about"></a>
```

Is there any way I can prevent the dynamic addition of that `</a>` in line 3 to fix this? Or another method?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086360/how-do-i-wrap-link-to-around-some-html-ruby-code link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<%= link_to about_path(post.slug), class: "hexIn" do %>
      <img alt="rss feed" src="http://www.example/image.png" />
      <h1>Business Business Business </h1>
      <p>Ipsum Incorporated is going to do something</p>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Please check the indentation it's not looking perfect.

Comment: Giving it a shot now. I am seeing an error for 'undefined method stringify keys` which seems related to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986559/rails-undefined-method-stringify-keys. Testing it out now. Seems like you can't have other things going on (like the h1 and p) in the block. Trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: do block will do the job for you as you required.

Comment: Hey, figured it out. It's the `link_to` - the params should be passed in the first chunk like this: `<%= link_to about_path(post.slug), class: "hexIn" do %>`. If you update your answer, I'll upvote as it works.